# Tkinter ttk.Progressbar: How to change the graphical length/width of the progress bar?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

So I was messing around with the progressbar in ttk, but I was wondering how to change its length. Not like the numerical value of its length, but the actual visual length of the progressbar.

With other widgets, I would just to 'width=27' or whatever and change it that way, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't it have a `length` option?

Comment: Run `print(ttk.Progressbar.__init__.__doc__)` and you will see all of the options that you can pass in. As CoolCloud pointed out, there is a `length` option

Comment: @CoolCloud but doesn't the length option change the numerical value of the progressbar as well? Like if I want a progressbar with 100 as its max value, is there a way to make it appear longer while keeping its numerical value 100?

Comment: Adding to that, you can also use `print(ttk.Progressbar().keys())` to get some properties

Comment: By default, 100 is the maximum value. To change the maximum value, you have to use `maximum` option, all this is really there in the documentation.

Comment: @CoolCloud Ah okay I think I understand. So if I wanted to create like a health bar, I would set the maximum equal to what the max health was, the value equal to what the current health was. I was under the impression that length was the numerical value of the bar, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up from the comments:

- `ttk.Progressbar` does not have a `width` option unlike most widgets, but it has a `length` option.
- Do not confuse `length` as the maximum value of the progressbar, it is just the width of the progressbar(by default in pixels).
- The maximum value of progressbar can be set using the `maximum` option.
- To get a list of properties a widget accepts you can use `<Widget>().keys()` or if you want a detailed look ~ `<Widget>.__init__.__docs__` will return the docstring of widget's `__init__`(as TheLizzard said).

```
ttk.Progressbar(root, length=200, maximum=300) # 200 pixels wide and 300 is maximum value
```